# Can email sender reputation be improved by sending lots of emails to a single recipient?

Tags: email, amazon-ses

Normally, we send about 200 emails from our app a day via AWS SES (we use them to confirm new users' emails).

A few days ago we've sent a Privacy Policy Update to 370 000 of our users. Some of those users have complained about spam which has caused our complaint rate to go up to 0.18% (AWS recommends to maintain complaint rate up to 0.1%). Since we send so few emails a day it will take quite a lot of time to restore our account's complaint rate.

So, I wonder, is it possible to "fix" the complaint rate by sending, say, 500 000 emails to one single email account that I own? This way the complaint rate should go down in theory. Or can it actually damage my account's reputation because of such an unusual activity?

I couldn't find an answer to this question on the Internet which is surprising, considering how much spam I get

Comment: (I'm not your downvoter, but…) you're basically asking how to game your sender reputation. You can probably see how useful this would be to spammers even if you're not one yourself. This also isn't a coding question. I can't speak to AWS's internal systems, which are probably intentionally opaque, but blasting a dummy account would be too easy a workaround for spammers, so I doubt it'd work. [Here's a senders' best practices document](https://www.m3aawg.org/sites/maawg/files/news/M3AAWG_Senders_BCP_Ver3-2015-02.pdf) that may help you more generally.

Comment: I agree with Adam. Note that you mention two things here. Sender reputation and (AWS) complaint rate. Those are not the same. You might be able to trick the AWS complaint rate and get it under 0.1% by sending to the same email address, but this will not improve your sender reputation as perceived globally. On normal use, complaint rate and sender reputation might correlate, but I feel by hacking this rate, you only fool yourself.

Comment: What about making more domains? Like support@example.com --> support@example-mail.com and off course forward all emails received by support@example-mail.com to support@example.com

Comment: The idea of the complaint rate is that you do not annoy your recipients. Sending half a million emails to yourself won't improve that. Do you experience any issues with your current complaint rate? If not, what are you trying to achieve then?

Comment: @VictorManuel, "If not, what are you trying to achieve then?" - 1. AWS recommends maintaining the complaint rate below 0.1%, so just trying to make sure we comply with it, and keep as far away from 0.5%. 2. We might need to send another privacy policy update in a few months, and this could cause the complaint rate to go up again (and in my understanding, the privacy policy update is something that we have to send, no matter what the users' subscription preferences are), and this is something that could further increase the complaint rate, so I'm thinking how to fix the current complaint rate.

Comment: @VictorManuel, "If not, what are you trying to achieve then?" - 3. Just improve my understanding of AWS SES mechanisms for calculating the complaint rate

Comment: @VictorManuel, "Do you experience any issues with your current complaint rate?" - no, not right now, except for it being higher than recommended by AWS limit

Comment: @VictorManuel, "What about making more domains?" I think, this is not an option since SES seems to calculate the senders' reputation for the whole AWS account or at lest region. I guess, this might be a possible solution if our complaint rate goes above 0.5% - we could set up a SES account in a different AWS account, different region.